# NVIDIA card not shown as device by `lspci | grep -i vga`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I had installed NVIDIA drivers along with nvidia prime on Ubuntu 12.04, to run CUDA-based applications in a first time. Then, I created a mess on the system because I installed Bumblebee as well, but I was not aware about the incompatibility issues between Bumblebee and nvidia prime. As a result, nothing more worked. Now I would like to recover the previous configuration.

However, if I type on terminal `lspci | grep -i vga` the only output item is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

that is the inner intel chipset of my laptop. As you see, the NVIDIA graphic card does not appear (of course it did when everything worked). I also tried to install the `nvidia-340` driver, but after the reboot the system does not detect the card yet.

In addition, but I don't know if it is correlated, I'm not able to install `nvidia-prime` anymore. When I try to do that, the output is:

```
Package nvidia-prime is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available 
from another source

E: Package nvidia-prime has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone knows where the issue lies?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
```

Reason is that for some video cards, they're not listed as a

- `[0300] VGA compatible controller`

they could be:

- `[0380] Display controller`
- `[0302] 3D controller`

Comment: still not showing for me, after reading all entries of `lspci -nn` no signs of it. Also can't find any settings in BIOS related to a second video card. I have a Precision 5520 with official ubuntu support, and although the "build your config" page clearly showed it comes with a NVidia card I'm beggining to doubt it has one.